# Modern art in Islam

Tags: practical-islam

I wish to know which types of art mentioned below are objectionable from Islamic point of view. I will provide the links later.

There are two types of art one that higlight(religious, authoratative figures or portrait) that clearly leads to idolism and iconism(and obviously harmful) and other Visual art using elements of a scene(figurative and non-figurative one) to

I. Painting of the image formed in our eye, photography or computer 
    generated one
(i) Preserve an actual observation by artist for others to watch.
(a) It is used for dispaly in art gallery(b) Higlight social and cultural 
    issues (b) Entertainment/education programs (c) Understand the way our 
    brain makes a picture by psychologist, neurologist.

II. Painting of the mental imagery formed in mind of artist

(ii) Draws an abstract visual scene showing how the artist perceives the 
     world around him. 
 (a) Used to show expressions or mood as observed by artist (b) 
     Experimenting with different geometrical principles of picture and 
     its elements drawing

Here is the hierarchal relation-ship leading to drawing a scene

Objective World(Created by Allah)->Visual World(Perceived by Five Senses, Photograph)->Mental Image(of Artist)->Portrayed on Canvas, Paper or computer

So any type of painting is twice removed from reality.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islm SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about this site and model I strongly recommend yout to take our 2 min. [tour] and check our [help].